# MS SQL сервер. Мониторинг и отключение запросов

Tags: sql-server, парсер, мониторинг

Имеется MS SQL сервер используемый бизнес-аналитиками для подготовки отчетности. Владение sql этих людей сильно разнится, поэтому нужно мониторить их запросы на предмет излишне кривых конструкций. Например исключить любые запросы вида **select into**. Или же находить когда используется **distinct/group by** по текстовым полям( зачастую это исправление ошибок в сути запроса, а не реальная необходимость). По сути нужно считать запрос, разобраться его и если есть признаки ошибок - отключить **SPID(server process id)** в рамках которого запрос выполняется. Для считывая запроса и отстрела можно обойтись встроенным функционалом. Проблема в разборе. Есть ли готовые решения данной задачи? Возможно какие-то готовые udf функции или расширения для MS SQL сервера?